# regex: how to get repeating blocks as groups()?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

Assume that we have a string such as `'{ CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE }'` and `'{ CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE, CAN_REMOVE }'` and want to extract the elements (`CAN_READ`, `CAN_WRITE`, `CAN_REMOVE`).  We assume that the number of elements can be any. I am trying to solve this with Python's regular expression module (`re`).

The regular expression I designed is like this: `r'^\{(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*,?)+\s*\}$'`

I think this regexp is correct as `re.match` works.  However, although I expect we can get elements with the `groups()` method of the result, it returns only the last match.

e.g.

```
>>> value='{ CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE }'
>>> re.match(r'^\{(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*,?)+\s*\}$', value).groups()
(' CAN_WRITE ',)
>>> value='{ CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE, CAN_REMOVE }'
>>> re.match(r'^\{(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*,?)+\s*\}$', value).groups()
(' CAN_REMOVE ',)
```

In order to test the block part `(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*,?)` is correct, I repeated this block twice, and it worked:

```
>>> value='{ CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE }'
>>> re.match(r'^\{(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*,?)(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*,?)\s*\}$', value).groups()
(' CAN_READ,', ' CAN_WRITE ')
```

However this works only when the number of elements is two.

How can I get all repeated blocks?

Comment: As usual: if you can install PyPi regex library, use `match.captures(1)`, else, do it in two steps: a) validate with `re.fullmatch`, then 2) extract the matches using either another regex or using split + a bit of string manipulation code. If you do not care about the string format validity, use `re.findall()` with an unanchored pattern that matches what is inside the braces (here, `re.findall(r'\w+', text)`).

Comment: Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: I tried both the two step approach and `re.findall()` and both worked.  `re.findall()` looks easier in my case. Thanks!